Float Switch and relay for pump
I have a pump that's only required for the occasional use with excess water, - https://www.al-ko.net.nz/alko-product-range/sub-6500-classic -  and this is only required when the water is 50-70mm deep. The built in float switch isn't much use at these depths obviously and I was trying to work out if I can either replace the existing float switch with something like a 240v 10w switch and a relay - https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32821729336.html + https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32844411297.html, or wire in the switch and relay to the supply?
I've only got the single 240v supply running to the pump location
I've tested the relay and switch with a light to test, they are all working if I jump the neutral from the common to the coil, and split the phase to both common and the coil. But concerned this will draw across the reed switch when on.
I know I could run from the NC but I'm trying to work out how to wire this so as to not consume power when off, but also not pull the load through the switch and coil when on.
Edit to try add a diagram of what I was thinking.

Hopefully the above makes sense and any guidance would be appreciated.
I'm wondering if this would be easier and better (potentially replaced with a 12v relay as per Fredled) -


Please draw your circuit and lose the appropriate wording that won't be needed any more.

I've added a diagram with my original thinking, hopefully it's clear, was trying with smartdraw.

Neither of the drawings show where the pump gets it supply voltage from. The first schematic will anyway not work.

Theoretically, the combination of this float switch and the relay should work and it won't consume any current as long as the switch is off. However, I would not trust the safety of these float switches on the long term, with 240V.
My recommendation is to connect this float switch to a 12V source and use a 240V relay actuated with a 12V input.
You can use such module for that effect.
The 12V power supply will consume a little bit (+-0.5W) permanently but you will be safe. And it will be better than a leak at 240V because the stainless steel started to rust.

Thanks @Fredled, that makes sense and I can order a plastic 12v float switch and small 12v power supply that could tap off the same feed. I've tried to add a diagram into the main post with my original thinking.
